# Developing an app which works as a DND application and blocks all the notifications for given time

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, notificationmanager

I am a beginner to android and I want to develop an application which blocks all the other app notifications for some period of time. Is it possible to block other app notifications ? **If it is possible, can someone guide me for that?** Can anyone please help me with this?

I have used one approach which is the method of `InterruptionFilter` but that doesn't work. Below is my code where I have used it.

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

//On button click calling the below method
mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

`NotificationListenerService` is the best fit for this.

A service that receives calls from the system when new notifications are posted or removed, or their ranking changed.

To extend this class, you must declare the service in your manifest file with the `Manifest.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission and include an intent filter with the `SERVICE_INTERFACE` action. For example:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
          android:label="@string/service_name"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Documentation : [NotificationListnerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

Probably You need to implement the methods like `cancelAllNotifications()` , `cancelNotification(String key)` to block other app notifications.